# Android: Simple Listview not displaying strings from array using startActivityForResult()

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I have two activities. My main and my second main and i add my string in my second main and press the back button to go to my first main.
 However when I pass the array to listview in arraylist adapter it doesn't work.

```
 ArrayList<String> array= new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_address_list);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


}
private void Add() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AddressList.this, SilentGeofence.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 2) {
       String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
            array.add(result);
       System.out.println(array);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_address_list,array);
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Here is my second view

```
  Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            String ag = txt1.getText().toString().trim();
            if (ag.length() != 0) {
                address.add(ag);
                txt1.setText("");
                System.out.println(address);
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent(SilentGeofence.this,AddressList.class);
                returnIntent.putExtra("result",address);
                setResult(2,returnIntent);

            }
        }

    });
```

here is my addresslist xml.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.anusha.app.AddressList"
>


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Comment: whats there in your activity_address_list xml
Does it contain listview or the textview for that listview

Comment: for the items inside your listview you should create a separate xml layout file and pass that layout file and id of the textview to the arrayadapter constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you should do is create another xml file with a textview for that listview

```
    <TextView
       android:id="your id"
       android:layout_width=""
       android:layout_height=""/>
```

and do this

```
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.textviewlayout,R.id.youridforthattextview,array);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first Activity:

```
String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
```

We know that your ListView is based on an ArrayList of Strings.  So you add the result:

```
array.add(result);
```

In your second Activity you have a String `ag`

```
String ag = txt1.getText().toString().trim();
```

It looks like you're adding it to a list

```
address.add(ag);
```

But instead of the string you're returning the list

```
returnIntent.putExtra("result",address);
```

Maybe you meant to return the String `ag`?

```
returnIntent.putExtra("result",ag);
```